# How to compare two strings in if else condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to compare two strings and I have written this code:

```
...
...
Declare @LTN as nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @LTN = LicenceTypesNames 
FROM tbLicence 
WHERE LicenceType = @LicenceType

IF @LTN != @LicenceTypesNames
   DELETE FROM tbCompanyAgent  
   WHERE LicenceNumber IN (SELECT DISTINCT LicenceNumber 
                           FROM tbLicence 
                           WHERE LicenceType = @LicenceType)  

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbLicence]( ...) 
ELSE 
   INSERT INTO  [dbo].[tbLicence](...)
```

Note that `@LTN` contains string like "Property & Casualty, Life"
and @LicenceTypesNames contains string like "Life,".

In this situation it should perform both insertion and deletion operations
and if both are equal then it should perform insertion operation only.

The above code is not checking condition properly!!!

Please help !!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after an `IF`, only **one** statement will be executed conditionally, *unless* you add a `BEGIN....END` block.

So in your case here:

```
IF @LTN != @LicenceTypesNames
   DELETE FROM tbCompanyAgent  
   WHERE LicenceNumber IN (SELECT DISTINCT LicenceNumber 
                           FROM tbLicence 
                           WHERE LicenceType = @LicenceType)  

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbLicence]( ...) 
ELSE 
   INSERT INTO  [dbo].[tbLicence](...)
```

**only** the `DELETE` is conditional on that `IF` check you have - but the first `INSERT` will **always** be executed!

You need to change this to:

```
IF @LTN != @LicenceTypesNames
BEGIN   -- ADD THIS!!
   DELETE FROM tbCompanyAgent  
   WHERE LicenceNumber IN (SELECT DISTINCT LicenceNumber 
                           FROM tbLicence 
                           WHERE LicenceType = @LicenceType)  

   INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbLicence]( ...) 
END    -- ADD THIS!! 
ELSE 
   INSERT INTO  [dbo].[tbLicence](...)
```

to get what I think you're trying to do ....